# Работа со звуком DirectSound

Tags: c#

Как можно воспроизвести mp3 файлы с помощью функций библиотеки DirectSound на С#? Wav-файлы научился без проблем

```
device = new Device();
device.SetCooperativeLevel(this, CooperativeLevel.Normal);
sound = new SecondaryBuffer(filePath, device);
sound.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);
```

А вот с воспроизведением mp3 проблема:

```
Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentException" в  Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.dll
```

Дополнительные сведения: Значение не попадает в ожидаемый диапазон.

Пытался так:

```
stream = new Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.Buffer(filePath, device);
stream.Play(0,BufferPlayFlags.Default);
sound = new SecondaryBuffer(stream, device);
sound.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);
```

все тоже самое.

Answer (score 4):

Библиотека **Direct Sound** не поддерживает форматы **mp3**.
Для воспроизведения `mp3`-файлов можно воспользоваться другой тулзой - [Direct Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: блин, ну опередил:D

Comment: @dDevil, следующий вопрос твой )